# responsive layout with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i have a layout which each row has 4 divs, now in mobile i want to change 4 divs to 2 divs like image

[image]

here is my code

```
<v-layout wrap align-center>
    <v-flex
        v-for="n in 10  "
           :key="n"
           xs3
           >
           <p>testtttt</p>
     </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Example from Vuetify
https://codepen.io/thanhtungvo/pen/Padagq?&editors=100
current there are 3 images, how to change 2 images and keep the max-width in mobile version(responsive)
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

thanks for Vuetify, it can be fixed like that

```
<v-flex
  v-for="i in 4 "
    :key="i"
     xs6
     md3
>
```

xs6: for small screen
md3: for medium screen
other metrics can check on the document 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/display

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-flex v-for="i in 6" :key="i" xs6>
```

Comment: no, i mean it automatically change to 2 items when mobile. Not change on the code